# Error using request-promise in node.js to print external api data to console

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I am just trying to print some data to the console to make sure my node.js app is receiving data to manipulate. I have formatted my code like so.

```
const rP = require('request-promise');

rP({
    'method'  : 'GET',
    'uri'     : 'https://football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/matches',
    'json'    : true,
    'headers' : {
        'X-Auth-Token' : 'api-key'
    },
    'insecure': true
})
.then(console.log, console.log);
```

The error I get back is

```
RequestError: Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: football-data.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:api.football-data.org
```

I have tried adding " 'insecure' : true " to the parameters to no effect as suggested in another answer. Also that same answer suggested using 'self-signed certificates' and pointed me [here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/643c43ab7be269a1efaa080ff05a18fff3f64cd7/README.md#using-optionsagentoptions). I am new to node.js so am unfamiliar with making api calls from the server and do not understand the information in the link about self-signed certificates.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Apologies if this question is incorrectly formatted, it's my first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `rejectUnauthorized: false` to object you pass to request. Albeit, this is not good idea from security point of view,